# Need to count days open in a month based on multiple openings and closings

Tags: excel, days

I'm trying to count the number of days a given location is open in a month based on multiple re-openings and re-closings.

[image]

Comment: I suggest you use VBA for that. Perhaps a UDF.

Answer (score 1):

### UDF1

Here is an example of user defined function:

```
Function FunDaysOfMonth(RngFrom As Range, RngTo As Range, RngIn As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim DatDate01 As Date
    Dim DatDate02 As Date
    
    'Setting DatDate01 as the later betweeen RngFrom.Value and the first day of the month of RngIn.Value.
    DatDate01 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(RngFrom.Value, _
                                            RngIn.Value - DateTime.Day(RngIn.Value) + 1 _
                                           )
    
    'Setting DatDate01 as the earlier betweeen RngTo.Value and the last day of the month of RngIn.Value.
    DatDate02 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Min(RngTo.Value, _
                                            DateAdd("m", 1, RngIn.Value) - DateTime.Day(RngIn.Value) _
                                           )
    'Setting FunFaysOfMonth.
    FunDaysOfMonth = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(DatDate02 - DatDate01 + 1, 0)
    
End Function
```

Place it in a module of your workbook. Then you can write in cell L4 a formula like

```
=FunDaysOfMonth($D4,$E4,L$3)+FunDaysOfMonth($F4,$G4,L$3)+FunDaysOfMonth($H4,$I4,L$3)
```

---

### UDF2

You can also use a more sophisticated user defined function like this one:

```
Function FunDaysOfMonthWithRanges(RngFrom As Range, RngTo As Range, RngIn As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim DatDate01 As Date
    Dim DatDate02 As Date
    Dim DblDateCount As Double
    
    'Checking if the cells count of RngFrom is equal to the one of RngTo.
    If RngFrom.Cells.Count <> RngFrom.Cells.Count Then
        
        'Setting FunDaysOfMonthWithRanges.
        FunDaysOfMonthWithRanges = "#DateMissing"
        Exit Function
        
    End If
    
    'Covering each couple of cells.
    For DblDateCount = 1 To RngFrom.Cells.Count
        
        'Checking if there is a mismatch between the two dates in the given cells of RngFrom and RngTo.
        If Excel.WorksheetFunction.Small(RngFrom, DblDateCount) > Excel.WorksheetFunction.Small(RngTo, DblDateCount) Then
            FunDaysOfMonthWithRanges = "#DateMismatch"
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        'Setting DatDate01 as the later betweeen the value of the given cell of RngFrom and the first day of the month of RngIn.Value.
        DatDate01 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Small(RngFrom, DblDateCount), _
                                                RngIn.Value - DateTime.Day(RngIn.Value) + 1, _
                                                DatDate01 _
                                               )
        
        'Setting DatDate01 as the earlier betweeen the value of the given cell of RngTo and the last day of the month of RngIn.Value.
        DatDate02 = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Min(Excel.WorksheetFunction.Small(RngTo, DblDateCount), _
                                                DateAdd("m", 1, RngIn.Value) - DateTime.Day(RngIn.Value) _
                                               )
        
        'Setting FunDaysOfMonthWithRanges.
        FunDaysOfMonthWithRanges = FunDaysOfMonthWithRanges + Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(DatDate02 - DatDate01 + 1, 0)
        
    Next
    
End Function
```

With this one you can pick range with multiple openings and closings (of the same shop). A formula in cell L4 will be like this:

```
=FunDaysOfMonthWithRanges(($D4,$F4,$H4),($E4,$G4,$I4),L$3)
```

---

### Note

In both case the dates have to be reported correctly. An opening overlap won't be noticed. For example: an opening from 02/02/2021 to 04/02/2021 and another one from 04/02/2021 and 07/02/2021 overlap for one day (04/02/2021) which will be count as an extra day. With 2 days overlapping, 2 extra days will be counted.